# Configuring Thymeleaf spring security 4 integration module using Yaml

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use spring security 4 integration module (https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity), Seems like I have to use java config and this can't be done in Yaml.

I'm not using any spring xml configuration. only Yaml and java configs.

Is there anyway to configure spring security integration module yet not mess up with thymeleaf auto configuration provided by Spring boot?

Right now I'm doing the configuration like this :

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    dialects.add(new org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect());
    engine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects);
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return engine;
}

private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    return resolver;
}
```

But I'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/thymeleaf/dialect/IProcessorDialect`
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Why would you need to configure anything... THe only thing you would need to do is, add the dependency... Spring Boot will configure the rest...

Comment: @M.Deinum according to https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity in the configuration section there is a configuration needed.

Comment: No there isn't... That applies to plain spring applications... Not to Spring Boot based applications. So in short, remove all your thymeleaf configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum now I'm getting ```Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authentication.isAuthenticated()" ``` I use it inside th:unless I want to hide and show it if the user is logged in.

Comment: Please specify which Spring Boot and Thymeleaf versions you are using.

Comment: @M.DeinumI'm using `Spring boot 1.4.1` with ```compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
 compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:3.0.0.RELEASE')``` in my build.gradle. Also the starter pom has ```provides: thymeleaf-spring4,thymeleaf-layout-dialect```

Comment: Please add it to the question not as comments.

Comment: Spring Boot by default uses thymleaf 2.1.5 not 3.0 0 So you are using incompatible versions.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum I added thymeleaf dependencies manually and it worked.